# Postgres get current schema name

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to get my current connection schema name I found that 'show search_path' returns the needed result but I need to use this result in the query.

How can I use "show search_path" in a Postgres query?

```
if not (SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 
  table_name = 'customer' and table_schema = **show search_path** )) then
do something ....
end
```

I need to use table_schema = show search_path

Comment: Something like `SELECT CURRENT_SCHEMA`?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `current_schema` function. It gives you the first schema on the `search_path` that actually exists, that is, the schema where unqualified tables will be created.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_name = 'project_customer_scheme'
  AND table_schema = (
    SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

select current_schema; -- This should give you the current schema